# scipy.optimize.basinhopping and total number of iter

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

**Is there a way to control total number of iter in basin hopping?**

With:

```
opt.basinhopping(self.objectiveFun, x0,minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, niter=20, disp = True)

minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "BFGS", "options":{"maxiter":50}}
```

My results are:

```
message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
  minimization_failures: 21
                   nfev: 3009
                    nit: 20
                   njev: 343
                      x: array([ 0.00041319, -0.0019854 , -0.00136236, -0.00012548,  0.02506612,
   -0.01001584])
```

Im counting loops over obj function which gets to 3009.

So I guess, that basin hopping does 20 "basin jumps" and about 3k of local opt loops? Which would mean that "options":{"maxiter":50} is either not defined correctly or not possible to define?
Thanks

Comment: The number of iterations is not the same as the number of objective function calls. BFGS calls the objective function multiple times per iteration (to estimate the gradient among other things).

Comment: @kazemakase thanks. I have changed the method to COBYLA, so the max(nfev) is now predictable.